How to write unit test case using Jamine to test form controls touched, untouched and dirty conditions
I have a form built using reactive forms angular and I have the below code.
The entire if conditions says , branch not covered, how can i make sure the branch is covered.
this.tableOptions.rowData.forEach((element:any)=> {
   if(element.type.toLowerCase() == "payments") {
       if(((this.oldValue == this.myForm.controls['nameControl'].value) 
      || (this.myForm.controls['nameControl'].untouched)
|| (this.myForm.controls['nameControl'].touched && !this.myForm.controls['nameControl'].dirty))){

......
}

})


You have to mock the conditions so that the execution goes inside the if condition.
Also note, I am failing all two if conditions, except the last, this is to demo a simple method to cover chained conditions with only one test case.
it('should cover the code', () => {
    component.tableOptions = {
        rowData: [{type: "payments"}],
    } as any;
    component.oldValue = 'test';
    component.myForm = {
        controls: {
            nameControl: {
                value: 'tester',
                untouched: false,
                touched: true,
                dirty: false,
            }
        },
    } as any;
});

